# difference between Stop, Immediate Stop and Terminate in WAS6.1

Tags: jakarta-ee, websphere, websphere-6.1

What is the difference between "Stop", "Immediate Stop" and "Terminate" in case of a Websphere Application Server instance.
Specifically in the context of in-flight requests and in-flight transactions at the time.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Stop, trys to stop the server by letting all processes finish and shutting down all communication.

Immediate stop: Stops the server, but bypasses the normal server quiesce process that would allow in-flight requests to complete before shutting down the whole server process. This shutdown mode is faster than the normal server stop processing, but some application clients may receive exceptions.

Terminate: Just kill the app and deal with problems later :-)

Answer (score 1):

Information on in-flight requests are covered here - http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v6r1/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.websphere.express.doc/info/exp/ae/urun_rsvr.html

Comment: This site talks about "quiesce process"
Stop - normal quiesce process is followed
Immediate Stop - quiesce process not followed
Terminate - quiesce process not followed?

Do you have any details about the quiesce process? Is it just a wait time to allow for in flight requests to complete? What does WAS do with inflight JTA txns during either of the above 3 shutdowns?


Thanks